# Row-wise sum of first, second and third highest values

Tags: r

Considering the following sample data:

```
"A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "L" "K"
"1" 2.59 23.08 4.61 10.32 5.61 0.05 0.34 24.04 19.34 5.76 4.27
"2" 23.31 1.84 15.34 1.23 0 0 6.13 12.88 6.13 17.18 15.95
"3" 9.47 0 13.68 9.47 0 0 0 2.11 5.26 6.32 53.68
"4" 2.16 29.99 4.58 7.92 0.92 0 0 8.97 16.57 12.05 16.83
"5" 5.4 76.35 2.06 8.87 0 0 0.26 0.39 0.9 2.7 3.08
"6" 8.24 30 7.65 0 1.18 0 0 4.71 22.94 23.53 1.76
```

I am struggling to find a solution that **row-wise** find and sum the three highest values.

Any idea?

Comment: use *apply*, sort and choose the first three.

Comment: How can I sort row-wise?

Comment: *apply(data, 1, function(x) sort(x, decreasing = TRUE))*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the transpose, and `map` over each column with `top_n(3)` and `sum`:

```
library(tidyverse)

tdf <- as.data.frame(t(df)) 
var_names <- names(tdf)

var_names %>%
  map_dfc(~tdf %>% select(.x) %>% top_n(3) %>% sum()) %>% 
  t()

    [,1]
V1 66.46
V2 56.44
V3 86.30
V4 63.39
V5 90.62
V6 76.47
```

Feels a bit hacky, but gets the job done.

**Update** A better way from Moody_Mudskipper:

```
var_names %>% 
  map_dfc(~tdf %>% select(.x) %>% top_n(3) %>% summarize_all(sum)) %>% 
  gather
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text='"A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "L"
2.59 23.08 4.61 10.32 5.61 0.05 0.34 24.04 19.34 5.76 4.27
23.31 1.84 15.34 1.23 0 0 6.13 12.88 6.13 17.18 15.95
9.47 0 13.68 9.47 0 0 0 2.11 5.26 6.32 53.68
2.16 29.99 4.58 7.92 0.92 0 0 8.97 16.57 12.05 16.83
5.4 76.35 2.06 8.87 0 0 0.26 0.39 0.9 2.7 3.08
8.24 30 7.65 0 1.18 0 0 4.71 22.94 23.53 1.76', header=TRUE)
```

^ Note: Slightly different data than OP, row numbers are removed.

Comment: I accept your answer because it is the only one and gets the job done though I am not a fun of `tidyverse` because I do not understand it much. Prefer `dplyr`

Comment: Glad it solved your problem.  FWIW, `dplyr` is part of `tidyverse` - the only additional `tidyverse` package here is with `purrr::map`, instead of using base R `apply()`.

Comment: Also - please accept whatever answer you feel is most suitable to your question.  The first answer is not always the best - especially, perhaps, in this case!

Comment: to avoid the 2nd transpose and type change I would suggest `var_names %>% map_dfc(~tdf %>% select(.x) %>% top_n(3) %>% summarize_all(sum)) %>% gather`

Comment: As noted in another response, `top_n()` includes ties so generates incorrect results, e.g., the third row.

Answer (score 6):

if you had a vector `x`, a function to calculate the sum of the three largest values might be

```
fun = function(x)
    sum(tail(sort(x), 3))
```

You'd like to apply this to each row of your object `m`

```
apply(m, 1, fun)
```

A somewhat faster (e.g., 40%) implementation is

```
colSums(apply(m, 1, sort, decreasing = TRUE)[1:3, ])
```

Or using partial sorting

```
colSums(apply(m, 1, sort.int, partial = 9:11)[9:11, ])
```

For performance, if there are many rows in `m`, avoid the iteration over rows implied by use of `apply()`. An implementation might be

```
library(matrixStats)
rowSums(m * (rowRanks(m) > ncol(m) - 3))
```

but this fails when there are ties in a row of `m`; `rowRanks()` does not support `ties.method = "first"`. Instead, implement our own `rowRanks()`

```
.rowRanks <- function(m) {
    m[] = sort.list(sort.list(m))
    rowRanks(m)
}
rowSums(m * (.rowRanks(m) > ncol(m) - 3))
```

For a tidyverse solution, it seems one wants to start with tidy data

```
tbl <- df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  gather("letter","value",-1) %>%
  group_by(rowid)
```

Solutions using `top_n()` generate incorrect results, so the best bet would seem to be

```
summarize(tbl, fun(value))
```

(`fun` could be expanded here, but that doesn't really seem to be a good idea because it makes it harder to separately modify and test).

Comparing the methods

```
f0 = function(m) apply(m, 1, fun)
f0a = function(m) colSums(apply(m, 1, sort, decreasing=TRUE)[1:3, ])
f0b = function(m) colSums(apply(m, 1, sort.int, partial = 9:11)[9:11, ])
f1 = function(m) rowSums(m * (.rowRanks(m) > ncol(m) - 3))
f2 = function(tbl) summarize(tbl, fun(value))
```

with

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> identical(f0(m), f0a(m))
[1] TRUE
> identical(f0(m), f0b(m))
[1] TRUE
> identical(f0(m), f1(m))
[1] TRUE
> identical(f0(m), f2(tbl)$`fun(value)`)
[1] TRUE
> microbenchmark(f0(m), f0a(m), f0b(m), f1(m), f2(tbl), times=10)
Unit: microseconds
    expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
   f0(m)  837.505  860.890  894.9245  905.9880  921.386  948.242    10
  f0a(m)  594.895  637.258  650.7217  653.1800  673.599  713.167    10
  f0b(m)  274.925  277.734  305.6551  296.2975  330.482  362.765    10
   f1(m)  166.416  169.290  192.8086  189.5945  215.491  219.478    10
 f2(tbl) 2265.451 2277.599 2425.6083 2327.7015 2359.896 3349.995    10

> m = m[sample(nrow(m), 1000, TRUE),]
> microbenchmark(f0(m), f0a(m), f0b(m), f1(m), times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
   expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
  f0(m) 137.705781 139.793459 141.658415 141.821540 143.653272 144.428092    10
 f0a(m)  85.946679  86.663967  88.500392  87.513880  89.634696  94.458554    10
 f0b(m)  29.762981  30.890124  32.470553  32.649594  33.116767  36.686603    10
  f1(m)   2.034407   2.120689   2.137723   2.144328   2.176306   2.184712    10
```

Answer (score 4):

using `tidyverse`:

```
df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  gather("letter","value",-1) %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  arrange(desc(value)) %>%
  slice(1:3) %>%
  summarize(value= sum(value))

# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   rowid value
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1     1  66.5
# 2     2  56.4
# 3     3  76.8
# 4     4  63.4
# 5     5  90.6
# 6     6  76.5
```

Alternate solution, inspired by @andrew_reece's solution:

```
tdf <- setNames(as.data.frame(t(df)),seq(nrow(df)))
tdf %>%
  summarize_all(~sum(tail(sort(.),3))) %>%
  gather(rowid,value)

#   rowid value
# 1     1 66.46
# 2     2 56.44
# 3     3 76.83
# 4     4 63.39
# 5     5 90.62
# 6     6 76.47
```

note:

the real `tidyverse` way to do `setNames(as.data.frame(t(df)),seq(nrow(df)))` would be as follows:

```
df %>%
  rowid_to_column %>%
  gather("letter","value",-1) %>%
  spread("rowid","value")
```

Comment: Really nice diverse set of tidyverse solutions.

Comment: The last one is really yours, that I tried to make more "tidyverse"

Comment: The solutions using `top_n()` generate incorrect results, because they include ties; see the third row.

Comment: Thanks I fixed it, I removed the last solution as it didn't look good anymore when fixed

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- read.table('"A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "L" "K"
"1" 2.59 23.08 4.61 10.32 5.61 0.05 0.34 24.04 19.34 5.76 4.27
"2" 23.31 1.84 15.34 1.23 0 0 6.13 12.88 6.13 17.18 15.95
"3" 9.47 0 13.68 9.47 0 0 0 2.11 5.26 6.32 53.68
"4" 2.16 29.99 4.58 7.92 0.92 0 0 8.97 16.57 12.05 16.83
"5" 5.4 76.35 2.06 8.87 0 0 0.26 0.39 0.9 2.7 3.08
"6" 8.24 30 7.65 0 1.18 0 0 4.71 22.94 23.53 1.76')
```

According to @Soheil suggestion, an R Base solution:

```
rowSums(t(apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x) sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)))[ , c(1,2,3)])
```

Comment: Here's a more compact version, mainly reworking syntax but also avoiding a transposition: `colSums(apply(df,1,sort,TRUE)[1:3,])`